# Trying to compute the heat capacity for the 2D-Ising model

Tags: random, physics, algorithm, simulation

I'm trying compute the heat capacity $C_v$ out of my simulation for the 2D-Ising model which is given by 
$C_v = \frac{\langle E^2 \rangle - \langle E \rangle^2}{T^2N^2}$ ($E$: Energy, $T$: Temperature, $N$: Number of points).
I implemented the Ising simulation using the Metropolis-method which seems to be the easiest way to simulate this:

```
Ising[n_, count_, B_, J_, T_] := Module[{}, 
e1 = 0; e2 = 0; 
dE[a_, b_]= a*2*(B - b*J)/T;
Lat = 2*Table[Random[Integer], {n}, {n}] - 1;

flip =
  (
 L = #;
 {i1, i2} = {RandomInteger[{1, n}], RandomInteger[{1, n}]};

 If[i1 == n, down = 1, down = i1 + 1];
 If[i2 == n, rechts = 1, rechts = i2 + 1];
 If[i1 == 1, up = n, up = i1 - 1];
 If[i2 == 1, links = n, links = i2 - 1];
 Es = L[[down, i2]] + L[[up, i2]] + L[[i1, rechts]] + L[[i1, links]];
 If[ dE[ L[[i1, i2]], Es ] < 0 || 
   RandomReal[] < Exp[-dE[ L[[i1, i2]], Es ]], 
  L[[i1, i2]] = -L[[i1, i2]]; e1 = e1 + dE[ L[[i1, i2]], Es ]; 
  e2 = e2 + dE[ L[[i1, i2]], Es ]*dE[ L[[i1, i2]], Es ], L; 
  e1 = e1; e2 = e2];
 L
 ) &;


fliplist = NestList[flip, Lat, count];
  ]
```

This simulation is working for the plots of the lattice.

But as I try computing the terms $\langle E \rangle$ and $\langle E \rangle^2$ and using them to compute $C_v$ the result is not what I am expecting.

For large numbers of iterations (in this case equivalent to time units $t$) the mean value of the energy can be computed by:

$\langle E \rangle = \frac{1}{count} \sum_{t=0}^{count} E_t$

The sum over $E_t$ is what i thought i was doing with the e1 and e2 in the code. 
As i repeat the simulation for several temperatures and then use the values to calculate $C_v$ the result is not the heat capacity.

```
Do[steps = 50000;
  Ising[64, steps, 0, -1, i]; Subscript[epts, i] = 1/steps e1; 
  Subscript[esq, i] = 1/steps e2,
  {i, 1, 3, 0.1}];

Do[Subscript[c, i] = 
  1/(2*i*i) (Subscript[esq, 
      i] - (Subscript[epts, i])*(Subscript[epts, i])), {i, 1, 3, 0.1}];
```

The plot of those points looks like this:
[image: C_v vs Temperature]

This is not the expected plot for $C_v$. There should be a peak at around 2.3.

Could anybody help me to calculate the real $C_v$ because I can't find the mistake. 
I'm very thankful for any help!

Comment: What are your axes? *Around* 2.3? So possibly you have missed this with too few of plot points?

Answer (score 9):

For this question, I can find some code of python version, [Refs. here](https://rajeshrinet.github.io/blog/2014/ising-model/). And I rewrote this Ising simulation as Mathematica version, as follow,

### 1. Define a function used for generating a table (as configuration)

```
Initialstate[n_Integer] := 2*Table[RandomInteger[], {n}, {n}] - 1
```

where `n` as the number of points. And define a function used for getting any point's neighbor.

```
GetNeighbor[x_Integer, y_Integer, size_Integer] := {{If[x - 1 > 0, x - 1, size], y}, {x, 
    If[y - 1 > 0, y - 1, size]}, {If[x + 1 <= size, x + 1, 1], y}, {x,
     If[y + 1 <= size, y + 1, 1]}} /; (0 < x <= size && 0 < y <= size)
```

### 2. Monte Carlo move using Metropolis-method

```
MCMove[config_, beta_] := 
 Module[{a, b, s, nb, cost, size = Length@config, 
   configReturn = config}, Table[
   a = RandomInteger[{1, size}];
   b = RandomInteger[{1, size}];
   s = config[[a, b]];
   nb = config[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ GetNeighbor[a, b, size] // 
     Total; cost = 2*s*nb;
   If[cost < 0, s = s*(-1), 
    If[RandomReal[] < Exp[-cost*beta], s = s*(-1)]];
   configReturn[[a, b]] = s, size*size]; Return@configReturn]
```

where `config` is random number table generate by `Initialstate` function.

### 3. Define some functions used to get the energy of the given configuration

```
Energy[config_] := Module[{energy, size = Length@config},
  Total[Table[-config[[i, 
        j]]*(config[[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ GetNeighbor[i, j, size] // 
        Total), {i, 1, size}, {j, 1, size}], 2]/4
  ]

GenerateEnergyTable[config_, tStart_Real, tEnd_Real, nt_Integer, 
  eqSteps_Integer, mcSteps_Integer] := 
 Module[{TList = Subdivide[tStart, tEnd, nt], config0 = config, 
    energyList, n = Length@config},
   energyList = 
    Function[t, config0 = Nest[MCMove[#, 1/t] &, config0, eqSteps];
        ({Total@#, Total[#^2]} &@
          Table[(config0 = MCMove[config0, 1/t]; Energy[config0]), 
           mcSteps])][#] & /@ TList;
   Transpose[{TList, energyList}]
   ] /; (Depth[config] == 3 && (#[[1]] == #[[2]] &@Dimensions[config]))
```

About parameters are described below:

- `tStart(tEnd)` : temperature start (end) point
- `nt` : number of temperature points
- `n` : size of the lattice, N x N
- `eqSteps` : number MC sweeps for equillibration
- `mcSteps` : number of MC sweeps for calculation

In particular, the function `GenerateEnergyTable` can generate a table, which includes *temperature*, $\sum E_i$ and $\sum E_i^2$. Next we define a function used to calculate heat capacity $C_v$.

### 4. Define Heat capacity function

```
HeatCapacity[energyTable_, mcSteps_Integer, 
  n_Integer] := {#[[
     1]], (#[[2]][[2]]/(mcSteps) - #[[2]][[1]]^2/(mcSteps^2))/(#[[
       1]]^2*n^2)} & /@ energyTable
```

### 5. Calculation

```
energylist = 
  GenerateEnergyTable[Initialstate[16], 1.53, 3.28, 88, 500, 500];
ListPlot[HeatCapacity[energylist, 500, 16], PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
  Filling -> Axis]
```

Runing above code, we can get one figure as below:

[image: The heat capacity for the 2D-Ising model]

As you said, it has a peak at around 2.3. I hope that these help you.

Furthermore, maybe you can use some method to improve the speed of calculation, such as compiled function, parallel calculation, etc...